# RewriteCond with OR statement

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a domain name with some fictive name called "domain-name.com". When someone writes into Web Browser one of these url addresses "domain-name.com" or "www.domain-name.com" then I need it to rewrite to "www.domain-name.com/eu" in both cases . How to achieve it?

I have finished with something like this but I do not know how to complete it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain-name\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name.com/eu/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to direct requests for "domain-name.com" and "www.domain-name.com" to the same domain name but with "/eu" appended. Here's one way to do that:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain-name.com$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain-name.com/eu [L,R=301]
```

That will grab requests for "domain-name.com" as well as "(any-characters-here)domain-name.com" and send them all to "http://www.domain-name.com/eu"